# java loop array using do...while

Tags: java, arrays, for-loop, do-while

This program should take a user defined number, create an array of that size and let the user input the elements - which are grades - using a do..while loop. The program then needs to display all grades entered from lowest to highest, accumulate the grades, and find the average.

My output isn't displaying the entered grades correctly (if I enter 10,20,30, it displays 00,10,20) and I can't figure out what I'm doing wrong. Any help, please?

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Scanner;

public class LoopArray
{
    public static void main(String[] arg)
    {
        Scanner keyboard = new Scanner(System.in);

        int count = 0;
        double totalAverage = 0;
        double gradesTotal = 0;

        System.out.println("Please input the number of grades you would like to submit for an average: ");
        int numberOfGrades = keyboard.nextInt();                 

        int[] studentScores = new int[numberOfGrades];

        do
        {
            System.out.println("Please enter grade for averaging: ");
            int inputGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
            count++;
            gradesTotal += inputGrade;

        } while (count < numberOfGrades);

        Arrays.sort(studentScores);

        for(count=0; count < studentScores.length; count++)
        {
           System.out.println("Grades entered were: " + count + studentScores[count]);
        }

        totalAverage = gradesTotal / numberOfGrades;
        System.out.println("The total of all grades entered is: " + gradesTotal);
        System.out.println("The average of grades entered is: " + totalAverage);

    }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are not putting any value inside the array. You need to add this to your do part of the loop `studentScores[count] = inputGrade;`
Now your `do while` loop should look like this:

```
do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade for averaging: ");
        int inputGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
        studentScores[count] = inputGrade;
        count++;
        gradesTotal += inputGrade;

    } while (count < numberOfGrades);
```

Also, inside your last `for-loop`, you are printing extra info. Just remove that count from `System.out.println`

```
 System.out.println("Grades entered were: " + studentScores[count]);
```

Anything you don't understand let me know thanks

Comment: That was it! Thanks so much! I was getting really frustrated. I appreciate it!

Answer (score 1):

Result

```
Grades entered were: 00
Grades entered were: 10
Grades entered were: 20
```

is generated with

```
System.out.println("Grades entered were: " + count + studentScores[count]);
```

So last number in each line is pair representing `count` + `studentScores[count]`. This means that:

- `00` -> at position `0` array `studentScores` stores `0`.
- `10` -> at position `1` array `studentScores` stores `0`
- `20` -> at position `2` array `studentScores` stores `0`

Which means you didn't fill your `studentScores` array with values from user.

Answer (score 0):

Because `count` start from 0. You should check it.

Answer (score 0):

you forgot to populate the array using the gardes entered

```
 do
    {
        System.out.println("Please enter grade for averaging: ");
        int inputGrade = keyboard.nextInt();
        studentScores[count]=inputGrade;
        count++;
        gradesTotal += inputGrade;

    } while (count < numberOfGrades);
```

Comment: It's not letting me upvote you or @FarazDurrani but thanks a lot!

Comment: @Jerstern You need 15 reputation to get [up-voting privilege](http://stackoverflow.com/help/privileges/vote-up). Anyway you can cast your votes later when you will get this amount of reputation (it is not that hard to get since each day there are thousands new of questions here:)

Comment: @FarazDurrani Another question on meta: [Is it reasonable to flag a comment asking for upvotes?](http://meta.stackoverflow.com/q/314258/1393766).

Comment: Definitely will once I hit 15. I'm still trying to grasp java at this point. As soon as it seems easy, a curve ball gets thrown, ha. Such is life. Thanks @Pshemo